# Webservice call hangs indefinitely

Tags: web-services, iis

I have a webservice that prints to a printer.
If the type of printer selected is one like the Office XPS printer or printing to a file such that user input is requested, the call from the client to the webservice hangs indefinitely.

I am running on Windows 7 and IIS 7 and there is no user input prompted for explicitly (ie not dialog box appears) and nothing appears in the event logs.

I am confused as to why the webservice call from the client to the service does not time out, as the service is running in release mode so the timeout is supposed to take effect.

I've searched around a lot on MSDN and here to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you track down when the connection hangs (using thread dump or something similar)? Maybe the timeout applies only to waiting for response whilst you hang at connection phase? Just a guess...

Comment: No the connection has been well established and code executed within the webservice and that code is hanging.